# solr core initialization error when adding new field to existing document

Tags: laravel

need to add a new field in an existing document but got this error

```
task: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load conf for core task: Error loading both non-managed schema 'schema.xml' and managed schema 'managed-schema'
```

I tried everything but nothing is working.

Answer (score 0):

```
Lets say solr is located at /usr/local/solr-5.5.0 .
1. bin/solr start
2. bin/solr create -c test
3. location of new core is here /usr/local/solr-5.5.0/server/solr/test
4. location of solrconfig is here /usr/local/solr-5.5.0/server/solr/test/solrconfig.xml
5. Open solrconfig.xml - 
    You will find this
     <schemaFactory class="ManagedIndexSchemaFactory">
       <bool name="mutable">true</bool>
       <str name="managedSchemaResourceName">managed-schema</str>
     </schemaFactory>
6. Change to    
      <schemaFactory class="ClassicIndexSchemaFactory">
      </schemaFactory>
7. Rename the managed-schema file( /usr/local/solr-5.5.0/server/solr/test/managed-schema ) to schema.xml.
8. Reload the core(s).
```